# WITH clause sub-query has non-unique column names

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using Oracle11g and looking to use WITH clause to create a named sub-query so that I could reference the "sub-query" results in multiple places. The issue that I am facing is sort of mimicked with the help of following dummy tables.

```
CREATE TABLE table1(id integer, region varchar2(20), xfunction varchar2(20), entity varchar2(20), xtime varchar2(20), usd binary_double);
insert into table1 values(1,'region1','function1','entity1','2018-01',1);
insert into table1 values(2,'region2','function2','entity2','2018-02',2);

CREATE TABLE table2(id integer, product varchar2(20), market varchar2(20));
insert into table2 values(1,'product1','market1');
insert into table2 values(2,'product2','market2');

CREATE TABLE table3(id integer, geo varchar2(20));
insert into table3 values(1,'geo1');
insert into table3 values(2,'geo2');
```

The following query is giving the error "ORA-00904: "V1"."ID": invalid identifier":

```
with v1 as
(
select
* -- want to select all columns, this is intentional
from
table1 a
left join table2 b ON 
a.id = b.id
),
v2 as
(
select * from v1
join table3 c on
v1.id = c.id -- gives error--> ORA-00904: "V1"."ID": invalid identifier
order by
c.id
)
select * from v2;
```

v1 has two columns with same column name (i.e. "ID"). How can I refer ID column of table1 from v1 (when ID column of table2 is also present in v1)?

I know that I could re-write the above query without using the WITH clause as a work around OR selecting only one ID column in v1. But what I am really looking for is to be able to use the WITH clause (with two ID columns in v1) and make it work. Is it possible?

Comment: Doesn't Oracle require naming the columns in a `WITH` statement? Such as in `with v1 (id, name, address) as (...`?

Comment: @The Impaler : No, `WITH <alias_name> AS (sql_subquery_statement)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle supports the `using` clause which does exactly what you want:

```
with v1 as (
      select *
      from table1 a left join
           table2 b 
           using (id)
     ),
```

In general, I prefer listing out the columns explicitly -- at least for one of the tables.  However, I also recognize the convenience of being able to express this.

Note:  This works only if `id` is the only duplicate column in the two tables.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Say if I have to match two tables on duplicate column as well as non-duplicate column then how will it work?

Comment: @SachinS . . . You would put the non-duplicate columns in a `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the issue is with join in v1 -

**a.id** = b.id

There is a column called id1 in table1 and not id. Running the same query with id1 gave me the output as -

```
ID1,REGION,XFUNCTION,ENTITY,XTIME,USD,ID,PRODUCT,MARKET,ID_1,GEO
1,region1,function1,entity1,2018-01,1.0,1,product1,market1,1,geo1
2,region2,function2,entity2,2018-02,2.0,2,product2,market2,2,geo2
```

Query -

```
with v1 as
(
select
* -- want to select all columns, this is intentional
from
table1 a
left join table2 b ON 
a.id1 = b.id
),
v2 as
(
select * from v1
join table3 c on
v1.id = c.id -- gives error--> ORA-00904: "V1"."ID": invalid identifier
order by
c.id
)
select * from v2;
```

Comment: That was a typo. I have edited my question for that.

Comment: So yours can not be said to be a valid answer now (after rectification of typo in the question). But thanks for pointing it out.